# Не работает Php форма с отправкой на сайт

Tags: php, html, telegram

Имеется php обработчик формы, который подключен к форме на Html лендинге , но при попытке отправить заявку мне просто открывается код обработчика. В чем может быть проблема?
Токен бота и айди канала скрыты, в оригинале указаны правильно.

Ниже будет код обработчика и сама форма

```html
<?php

$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
$email = $_POST['user_email'];
$token = "***";
$chat_id = "***";
$arr = array(
  'Имя пользователя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
  'Email' => $email
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};

$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");

if ($sendToTelegram) {
  header('Location: index.html');
} else {
  echo "Error";
}
?>
```

```html
 <form action="telegram.php" method="POST">
         <legend>Заголовок формы</legend>

         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Введите ваше имя</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_name" placeholder="Например, Иван">
         </div>
        
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Введите номер телефона</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_phone" placeholder="+7 (999) 99 99 999">
         </div>
        
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Введите email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="user_email" placeholder="mail@mail.ru">
         </div>
        
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить форму</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Полностью скопировал ваш код, всё работает правильно, меня смущает, что `просто открывается код обработчика`, единственное предположение, что проблема в хостинге, а именно, на хосте нельзя использовать php скрипты, это точно так же, как использовать php скрипт в файле, с расширением .html, код скрипта просто выведется на экран и никак не будет обработан сервером

Comment: смотрите что у вас с php на сервере